# Where can I report SC2 bugs to Blizzard? (also, check out this wild creep glitch)

Tags: starcraft-2, technical-issues

Took this with my phone hence it's not pixel accurate like a screen shot would be but you can see what I was seeing, I had been watching a Replay and switched my Textures graphics level then went and joined a 2v2 only to find my creep was looking kind of interesting... what the heck? Next game it went away, strange though! Is there any where I can report bugs? Anyone ever had this?

***EDIT: Also can anyone tell me where in the game they've seen this texture used possibly? My brother thought it might be the Protoss warp prism field or something.***

Creepy creep is creepy...
[image]

Comment: hehe Creepy Creep

Comment: @closers - in what way is this "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical"?  This seems like a perfectly legitimate question to me.

Comment: @sjohnston - The 'question' amounts to 'I just saw this'. There isn't anything to answer.

Comment: @Arda Xi - I could see how "has anyone else seen this bug" is closeable, but "Is there anywhere I can report bugs for SC2?" is, I think, a valid, answerable question.

Comment: @sjohnston - That question would have the title "Is there anywhere I can report bugs for SC2?" without the example.

Comment: @Shogun - It seems that the general consensus is that the question would be better titled something like "Where can I report bugs for SC2", whether or not the example remains within the body.  Currently, the title is two questions, and the "has anyone else seen this" portion is the bit causing contention.

Comment: thanks for the input everyone, I have updated the title of the question and hopefully it makes everyone happy :)

Comment: Do those symbols look like the Nod symbol from C&C to anyone else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the bug report forums: [US forum](http://forums.battle.net/board.html?forumId=2549861&sid=5000), [EU forum](http://forums.battle.net/board.html?forumId=25458886&sid=5010).

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen that particular bug, but it is a common enough type of glitch. Basically one texture is replaced for another. I have seen it happen in several games, often when playing on an older machine, a PC with a weaker graphics card, or when overloading a processor with lots of alt-tabbing etc. I am not sure if this happens due to some memory getting mixed up, the graphics card getting overworked, or due to a genuine bug in the program.

You can see similar examples in the post [Glitchstravaganza](http://wow.joystiq.com/2008/04/18/around-azeroth-glitchstravaganza/) at WoW.com. For example here is the WoW selection screen with messed-up textures:

[image: Glitch image]

As for the question of where that texture is from, I remember seeing it in one of the multiplayer maps. I forget which one, but if you have burning curiosity, you can play around in the map editor.

Comment: Memory doesn't just get "mixed up" on its own - his problem is, without a doubt, a bug in the game.

Comment: I know memory doesn't just jump around on it's own. =) But this bug could be due to other things like an overwhelmed graphics card. For example my last graphics card did this often before it died.

Comment: Textures being completely FUBAR-ed (as in the picture above) is understandable, if the card is defective or overheating.  However, textures being swapped due to overheating is so overwhelmingly unlikely I'd put money down in saying it'd never happen.