# Grid layout for lefties does not work with 'w' key

Tags: starcraft-2

I cannot get my <kbd>w</kbd> key to work in Starcraft 2. I can assign a hotkey to it in settings, and it works in the chat, so it obviously "works", but it never works for unit command hotkeys.

I have a bizarre setup I realize, but I cannot really live without it:

- I use Dvorak-International keyboard layout, because I use Dvorak, I use an American keyboard, and I frequently need to type international characters.
- I use grid for lefties in Starcraft 2

For some reason, the <kbd>w</kbd> key does not register at all during gameplay. This is the <kbd>c</kbd> for the normal grid layout. Bottom row, 3rd column of the grid.

This makes it impossible to use a hotkey for:

- Hallucination
- Transfusion
- Raven seeker missile

And others.

Anyone have a suggestion for a solution?

**Update**

I figured out that it is indeed the layout, and a bug in Starcraft 2. It seems that while Starcraft 2 handles alternate keyboards surprisingly well, it falls short. I found that Starcraft will consider it a duplicate when a dvorak key and its corresponding qwerty key are assigned. That's confusing...

For example, I assign <kbd>/</kbd> using my dvorak keyboard (that's the <kbd>[</kbd> key to you qwerty folks). Now I mysteriously cannot assign <kbd>z</kbd> (that's <kbd>/</kbd> in qwerty). There is no logical reason these should be considered duplicates; they are two physically different keys, so it seems that Starcraft 2 still uses the qwerty layout for some of its checking.

Man I can't think of a better way to explain it; that must be confusing.

Anyway I did as I said and totally revamped my keyboard layout anyway. I have to just live with a few "dead" keys.

Anyone know where I can file a bug report to Blizzard?

Comment: In regards to your latest edit, your question has been answered [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7566/where-can-i-report-sc2-bugs-to-blizzard-also-check-out-this-wild-creep-glitch). 'gratz on finding the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing its most likely because of your keyboard layout.  I would set up an alternate layout and a Windows hot key to switch to it for Starcraft 2.

I use U.S. International myself but I always make sure that I have a way to switch to U.S. Standard since I occasionally run into games which have issues with it.

Comment: Probably. Honestly I don't like the lefty grid that much though and I may create my own anyway which just avoids the issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do this via "keyboard setup" in-game menu.
In last tab of settings there are some misc buttons like 'voice chat'.. 'warpgates' hotkey is also here